# Generating AES IV from Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Tags: c#, security, encryption, aes

I am using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to generate an `AES` key and `iv`. However, I heard that the `iv` should not be dependent on the password. Here's how I'm doing it right now:

```
byte[] salt = GenerateRandomBytes(32); // Generates 32 random bytes
using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(plainStrPassword, salt)) {
    byte[] aesKey = rfc.GetBytes(32); 
    byte[] iv = rfc.GetBytes(16);    // Should I do this or generate it randomly?
}
```

My question: Is it OK (secure) to generate the `iv` from `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`? Or should I generate it randomly using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`?

Comment: Also take a look here: [Derive cipher IV and cipher Key using PBKDF2 with random salt?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26537).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not secure to derive the IV from the same source from which you derive the key. The IV exists so that encryption of identical messages under the same key produces different ciphertexts.

You should use a cryptographically secure random source (such as `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` you identified) to derive the IV and communicate it alongside the ciphertext (typically either prepended to the ciphertext as one stream of bytes or in a separate field within a more structured file format).

Comment: Ah. Ok, thanks. This is what I expected more or less

Comment: What are you saying in the first sentence implies that, if one is given the output of the PBKDF2 then you can find the password. Why does deriving the IV and Key from the output of a single PBKDF2 insecure? Can you elaborate on that? There are tons of password [hashing shemes](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes) using the PBKDF2

Comment: @kelalaka - I don't see how my sentence implies that. I'm saying that deriving the IV deterministically from the same material from which one derives the key is an error. This says nothing about being able to work backwards. IVs shouldn't be reused with the same key but in this situation you're guaranteeing that the same IV will be used each time the same key is used.

Comment: Your first sentence really implies that. The OP's code generates a single key and an IV for that. It is not a code to generate many IV's for a single key. The mode of operation is not mentioned and the SIV mode is quite secure against the IV re-use problems. It is designed for this case.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at your code;

```
byte[] salt = GenerateRandomBytes(32); // Generates 32 random bytes
using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(plainStrPassword, salt)) {
    byte[] aesKey = rfc.GetBytes(32); 
    byte[] iv = rfc.GetBytes(16);    // Should I do this or generate it randomly?
}
```

- **Random salt** - Good
- **Rfc2898DeriveBytes with salt**; this is good as long as the user password has good strength. The strength (not entropy!) of the derived key cannot exceed the passwords' strength.
- Call **GetBytes(32) for Key** - Good, this is what is expected.
- Call **GetBytes(16) for IV** -

This is good, too; [since](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.getbytes?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_Rfc2898DeriveBytes_GetBytes_System_Int32_)

> **Repeated calls to this method will not generate the same key**; instead, appending two calls of the GetBytes method with a cb parameter value of 20 is the equivalent of calling the GetBytes method once with a cb parameter value of 40.

For each encryption, you can continue to get a new IV by calling `GetBytes(16)`. Of course, there is a limit to that. PKKDF2 standard limits the output `2^32-1 * hLen`, see in [RFC 8018](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8018#section-5.2).

There is nothing wrong with outputting some part as IV and keeping some part as the encryption key. There are already tons of password schemes using PBKDF2 and non have been broken even the password hash and salt has been known.

If you are fearing that is not a good idea, then you can use either;

- Generate two salts and derive the IV and encryption key separately form password as;

```
byte[] saltForKey = GenerateRandomBytes(32); // Generates 32 random bytes
using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(plainStrPassword, saltForKey)) {
    byte[] aesKey = rfcKey.GetBytes(32);

byte[] saltForIV = GenerateRandomBytes(32); // Generates 32 random bytes
using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfcIV = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(plainStrPassword, saltForIV)) { 
    byte[] iv = rfcIV.GetBytes(16);    // Should I do this or generate it randomly?
}
```

- Generate random Salt and derive the encryption key and jus generate a random IV

```
byte[] salt = GenerateRandomBytes(32); // Generates 32 random bytes for Salt
byte[] IV = GenerateRandomBytes(16); // Generates 16 random bytes of IV

using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(plainStrPassword, salt)) {
    byte[] aesKey = rfc.GetBytes(32); 
}
```

---

Note that, you did not define the encryption mode. For a mode like

- CTR mode, the 96-bit nonce, and 32-bit counter are common. For this, the 96-bit nonce can be generated by a counter/LFSR, too. Make sure that a (key,IV) pair never occurs.
- CBC mode, the nonce must be random and unpredictable. The above is fine for this.
- Of course, you should forget those and use authenticated encryption modes like AES-GCM, ChaCha20-Poly1305. If you fear the IV reuse then use AES-GCM-SIV that can only leak that you sent the same message, nothing else leaked. SIV mode is just to times slower, since it must pass the plaintext to derive the IV, then encryption is executed.

Comment: I think GetBytes(16) generates a byte[] that is independent from GetBytes(32). I might be wrong though

Comment: The call `rfc.GetBytes(16)` in the OP's code doesn't return the first 16 bytes of the key, but the 16 bytes following the key. So the code of the OP is equivalent to your 2nd scenario with `GetBytes(48)`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.getbytes?view=net-5.0#remarks).

Comment: @Topaco, I've updated. Yes, each call has different. Could you a little check?

Comment: @Win32ApiUSer I've updated, Topaco right, the subsequent calls return different, so no danger there.

Comment: A minor typo, in the 2nd code snippet: `rfcIV.GetBytes(16)` must be applied when determining the IV. Apart from that everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

> Many cryptographic algorithms are expressed as iterative algorithms. E.g., when encrypting a message with a block cipher in CBC mode, each message "block" is first XORed with the previous encrypted block, and the result of the XOR is then encrypted. The first block has no "previous block" hence we must supply a conventional alternate "zero-th block" which we call "initialization vector". Generally speaking, an IV is whatever piece of data is needed to begin running an algorithm, and is not secret (if it was secret, we would call it a "key", not an IV).

IV is an arbitrary constant so any value will work. Make sure your encryptor and decryptor uses the same value. For more info you can refer these links:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/732/why-use-an-initialization-vector-iv

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/what-is-the-main-difference-between-a-key-an-iv-and-a-nonce

Comment: You're right, any value will work, but some values are not secure. For example, you shouldn't hardcode an `IV`.

Comment: Yes, you should not. You can use any random value for IV as long as you reproduce it or get it again.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But my question is is it safe to use an IV generated from the password?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-5.0), it is fine to use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` for generating iv from password. `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is implementation of PBKDF2, which the purpose is for: **password-based key derivation functionality**. See the example there.

PS: you should use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` for generating salt.